# MaterialButtonToggleGroup addOnButtonCheckedListener called twice every time

Tags: android, kotlin

For some bizarre reason, `addOnButtonCheckedListener` is called twice every time I click any of the buttons inside `MaterialButtonToggleGroup`. Below is my XML

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    tools:context=".ui.UserCartCheckout">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
            android:id="@+id/btgTest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:checkedButton="@id/btnTest1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:singleSelection="true"
            app:selectionRequired="true">
            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/btnTest1"
                style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Cash"
                app:icon="@drawable/cash"
                app:iconGravity="textStart"
                android:enabled="true" />
            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/btnTest2"
                style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Pay_With_Stripe"
                app:icon="@drawable/contactless_payment"
                app:iconGravity="textStart"
                android:enabled="true" />
        </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
</ScrollView>
```

and below is the code

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.btgTest.addOnButtonCheckedListener { group, checkedId, isChecked ->
            Timber.d("imini 177 isChecked: $isChecked")
            if (isChecked) {
                when (checkedId){
                    R.id.btnTest1 -> Timber.d("1 is checked")
                    R.id.btnTest2 -> Timber.d("2 is checked")
                }
            }else{
                Timber.d("imini 184")
            }
        }
    }
```

Every time I click the top button `btnTest1` my logcat will output

```
imini 177 isChecked: true
1 is checked
imini 177 isChecked: false
imini 184
```

and every time I click the bottom button `btnTest2` my logcat will output

```
imini 177 isChecked: false
imini 184
imini 177 isChecked: true
2 is checked
```

So as you can see, not only `addOnButtonCheckedListener` called twice every time I click on any buttons inside it, but when I click on the top button, it will always somehoow marked as `not checked`. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are working with a Grouped Toggle widget, the callback implementation is correct because:

1. The callback is fired when any item is checked / unchecked
2. This is happening because this is a single choice toggle group
3. When you select `Stripe`, the `Cash` item is unchecked which triggers another call to the callback with an updated value of `isChecked`.

If you want to only see what item is checked, follow this:

```kotlin
materialToggleGroup.addOnButtonCheckedListener { _, checkedId, isChecked ->
    // not observing the unchecked value
    if (!isChecked) return@addOnButtonCheckedListener

    when (checkedId) {
        R.id.btnTest1 -> log("1 is checked")
        R.id.btnTest2 -> log("1 is checked")
    }
}
```